# Class Source not found

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

"Jar file for selenium 3.0 is not found. source not found""I am getting this issue while I click on the ctrl+Selenium functions(like implicitwait() or switchTo()). 
How to resolve this one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHMZz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Subhasis Chandra,

I check and found your given screen-short. it jar file is configured. but the source code of this selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar isn't configured.
convert jar file source code using following service http://www.javadecompilers.com/
So the following step to configure source code.
1. Click Attach Source.. button in you getting source code not found.
2. select "External location" radio button
3. select Path "selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar.src.zip" using External file.
4. Click Ok.

Let's us know if you have any query.